# Income tax rules when spouses are tax residents for different countries (specifically France and UK)

Tags: income-tax, united-kingdom, france, marriage

I know tax laws are country specific and in case of spouses living in two separate countries they may depend on the specific countries due to tax treaties so my question cannot be asked in all generality so I will make it specific to France and UK.

If I go to work in UK and my wife stays in France with our child how will it effect computation of taxes for both of us. I know in France for instance the taxes are computed using household units and in our case we count for 2.5 units. I know taxes in France will be due only on the French part of the income but will it be computed using 2.5 units or 1.5?

If the latter then the tax burden becomes much more for spouses that have different tax residency.

Comment: The *quotient familial* system only applies if you choose to be taxed on the total income of the family (*soumis à l'imposition commune*). I am not 100% sure but it's difficult to see how that could be achieved in this case. It's not clear it would necessarily work to your advantage either (it depends on how high your income is relative to your wife's and how much tax you would pay in the UK). Would you spend much of your time in the UK?

Comment: For reference: [here is the relevant agreement](https://www.impots.gouv.fr/portail/files/media/10_conventions/royaume-uni/royaume-uni_convention-avec-le-royaume-uni-impot-sur-le-revenu_fd_5835.pdf)

Comment: @Relaxed Thanks for your answer. I was thinking of a situation where I'd spend all my time in the UK.

Comment: Meanwhile as you know, [I found some information suggesting](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/20856/tax-implications-for-one-spouse-with-uk-tax-residency-and-one-with-french/20864?noredirect=1#comment33846_20864) the *quotient familial* applies no matter what (which seems like a huge bonus rather than alleviating an undue tax burden to me, but that's anotther question) so my earlier comment was not 100% accurate.